# Override dynamic created table by webix from ltr to rtl

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a class `webix_column` with style `left : 0`.

I want to change it to `right : 0`.

How can I do it for all with the same value?

```
<div style="width: 80px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" column="2"  class="webix_column "> </div>
<div style="width: 80px; left: 250px; top: 0px;" column="2" class="webix_column "> </div>
<div style="width: 80px; left: 350px; top: 0px;" column="2" class="webix_column "> </div>
```

i tried to override to `left : 0` and `right:auto` but it didn't work

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying?

Comment: why don't you do `left: calc(100% - 80px);` instead? throw in `!important` if it's still getting overridden

Comment: left: calc(100% - 80px); not work

Comment: OK @dippas he just said that he has a table and trying to change its direction from ltr to rtl

Comment: i have dynamic table created with javascript by webix Library but i can't override from ltr to rtl

Comment: *Override dynamiclly created table by webix from ltr to rtl* this is exactly what your question title should be ya @MostafaMohamed

Comment: @MostafaMohamed this is my first time hear about webix  .. but! take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/5k4Lgbk8/  while `webix_column ` class should be absolute by default on webix .. I think this code will work

Comment: @MostafaMohamed finally! I got it . I think this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/00krrgnm/195/ :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it's work :) thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting left to auto and right to 0
please let me know if this works